# Sql/JavaScript: Retrieved boolean value shows up as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, sql, types, boolean

In my JavaScript I'm making an API call to retrieve a number of records in JSON format. The JavaScript function is defined as:

```
function retrieveScenarioObject() {
    $.getJSON(surl + "GetAllScenarios", function (data) {
        var output = JSON.parse(data);

        $.each(output, function(i, val) {
            console.log(output[i]);   // see below screenshot
            objScenario.scenario[i] = {};
            objScenario.scenario[i].id = output[i].Scenario_Id;
            /*  ...
                retrieving a bunch of attributes, many of which are omitted here
            */
            objScenario.scenario[i].preferredFlag = output[i].Scenario_Preferred_Flag;
            objScenario.scenario[i].creator = output[i].Scenario_Creator;
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
            // ... 
        }).complete(function () {
            // ...
        });
    });
}
```

Using IE's Developer console, I could verify that I'm actually getting the boolean attribute `Scenario_Preferred_Flag` and the corresponding value as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

However, when I actually try to retrieve the specific value by referencing the `output[i].Scenario_Preferred_Flag`, I get `undefined` in return. Referencing all other attributes the same way yield the correct values. So, I'm almost convinced that this problem has to do with the specific data type (i.e., boolean) but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I think it might be worth mentioning that I'm using SQL database and the attribute in question is of `bit` data type. I also double checked that every record I'm retrieving has a legitimate value for the attribute.

Comment: in your console, prefered has one r.

Comment: @Christian - Wow... having spent hours to resolve this issue and failing to catch that typo is downright embarrassing. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: it happens to us all :)